# Codeigniter Page linking

Tags: codeigniter-url, base-url

can someone please help me I'm using the codeigniter for my web-application and i'm trying to link to another page using the controller but my efforts have failed:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/architecture.php')?>">ARCHITECTURE & DESIGN </a></li>
```

and the outcome is a 404 page not found error message
could there be something i need to configure first?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<li><a href='<?php echo $this->config->config['base_url']; ?>index.php/controller_name/function_name'><span>ARCHITECTURE & DESIGN</span></a></li>
```